# the finite element method for fourth order problem

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

Consider the following boundary value problem:

$u^{(4)}(x)=x$,  $x\in (0,1)$,

$u(0)=u^′(0)=u(1)=u^′(1)=0$,

I want to solve this problem with the finite element method. But given the weak form of the equation in which the second-order derivative exists, I cannot use the basic functions of the first order. I want to know how this problem is solved in finite element method. Please guide me.

Comment: Yes, you need piecewise $C^2$ elements, with $C^1$ connections, like cubic splines.

Comment: Can you help me more?

Comment: You use cubic Bezier spline elements, for example, to build the function, or use cubic B-splines as basis functions of the Riesz-Galerkin method.

Comment: In the Bezier case, you use $(1-s)^3,3s(1-s)^2,3s^2(1-x),s^3$ as kernel functions inside an element, where $s$ is the parameter inside the element. The first and last give the function values at the nodes, while the inner terms modify the derivatives at the nodes, with enough freedom to do it independently.